More than one DbContext named 'ApplicationDbContext' was found. Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name using its exact case
Currently I am going to add my first migration. Please find the code for the player class. When I write
Add-Migration initialMigration 

I get following error:

More than one DbContext named 'ApplicationDbContext' was found. Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name using its exact case.

I have tried to use this instead:
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context ApplicationDbContext

But I still get the same error. Please let me know the solution so that I can add my first migration. I have given the connection string and there is already a database created in SQL Server Management Studio with a name of Players.
namespace Playersmanagementsystem.Models
{
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Emailaddress { get; set; }

        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

The ApplicationDbContext class code looks like this:
    using Playersmanagementsystem.Models;
    
    namespace Playersmanagementsystem.Context
    {
        public class ApplicationDbContext :DbContext
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
            {
            }
    
            public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        }
    }

Here's my appsettings.json:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server :DESKTOP-DFBVCE0;Database:Players; User Id=Ammadlogin;Password:ammadpass1; TrueServerCertificate:True"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

As I have selected individual accounts before creating an ASP.NET Core project so some of the code was written already in the DbContext.
The Program.cs code looks like this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Playersmanagementsystem.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

The name on my SQL Server is only DESKTOP-DFBVCE0 if go to the properties. Please let me know if it should be DESKTOP-DFBVCE0//SQLEXPRESS in the connection string.
Currently my goal is to have my first migration added for the model player. Thanks

If you perform a Find in Files, in the solution folder, for "class ApplicationDbContext", how many results do you get?

@flackoverstow it's a very useful point raised. I can see ApplicationDbContext one in the context folder created by me and one in Migration folder which is created automatically at some stage. I am not sure about the Migration folder because it haven't created till now.

should I delete the Migration folder or the duplicate ApplicationDbcontext.cs class file?

@flackoverstow . It has worked for me. The migration has been created after deleting the already automatic created Migration folder. Thanks a lot.
